# JSON integer automatically to string except id

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, vue.js

setup : 
- PHP 
- Vuejs / vueresource
- Laravel

In local everything works fine, in prod its fail .

In loca,, when I do a ajax request, I receive the item like this :

```
{"ad":{"id":7,"active":1,"url":null,"publish_date":"2018-03-12", ... .. .....
```

In prod, I receive it like this:

```
{"ad":{"id":7,"active":"1","url":null,"publish_date":"2018-03-12", ... .
```

The difference is the active prop in local it's really an integer, in prod a string.

I just don't understand.

Comment: We don't as well.  How do you think we are going to help with that statement?

Comment: Take a look here. I think it will be helpfull: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/laravelvue-boolean-returned-as-string

Answer (score 1):

Try [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting). From the docs:

> ### Attribute Casting
>
> The `$casts` property on your model provides a convenient method of converting attributes to common data types. The `$casts` property should be an array where the key is the name of the attribute being cast and the value is the type you wish to cast the column to. The supported cast types are: `integer`, `real`, `float`, `double`, `string`, `boolean`, `object`, `array`,  `collection`, `date`, `datetime`, and `timestamp`.
>
> For example, let's cast the `is_admin` attribute, which is stored in our database as an `integer` (`0` or `1`) to a `boolean` value:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App;
>
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
>
> class User extends Model
> {
>     /**
>      * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
>      *
>      * @var array
>      */
>     protected $casts = [
>         'is_admin' => 'boolean',
>     ];
> }
> ```
>
> Now the `is_admin` attribute will always be cast to a `boolean` when you access it, even if the underlying value is stored in the database as an `integer`:
>
> ```
> $user = App\User::find(1);
>
> if ($user->is_admin) {
>     //
> }
> ```

So, you need to define the correct way Laravel will cast the desired attribute. To do this just override the `$casts` array in your model class and specify your attributes (key) to the proper type (value).

/path/to/your/project/app/**SomeModel.php**

```
class SomeModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'active' => 'integer',
    ];

    // The rest of the model code.

}
```